# R: tweedie.dev function gives Inf

Tags: r, deviance, tweedie-distribution

I have a question regarding the function tweedie.dev(y, mu, power) from the tweedie package. When I run this function on some data I have generated I get Inf where y = 0 (I use power = 1.5). Does this function compute the deviance as per:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweedie_distribution#The_Tweedie_deviance?

If so, I do not see how it would ever give Inf, since there is no risk of dividing by zero as long as power is not equal to 1 or 2. Does anyone have any insights on this function, and why I get this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please tell us what this function is intended to compute?

Comment: Please see the wikipedia link i provided.